# New ethernet dual card hangs the server when doing ifconfig eth2 down

Tags: linux, networking, drivers

What I'm going to explain is happening on two different servers with same OS, same hardware and same hardware upgrade. IMHO I think may be a driver error is going on, but don't know how to figure it out.

I'm having some strange troubles with this server which is based on a SuperMicro motherboard.
The server runs red hat Linux.
The server "hangs" when I do "ifconfig eth2 down" , also with eth3.
This eth2 and eht3 belong to a new PCI card added last week. 
Eth0 and eth1 are integrated on the motherboard and they work with igb driver. 
Eth2 and eth3 are the new ones on a PCI card and depends on e1000e driver.

Eth0 is configured as follows and is working fine.

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.0.16.49
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=10.0.16.0
HWADDR=00:xx:xx:xx:xx:5c
```

Eth1 is configured as follows and is working fine.

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.16.46
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

Eth2 and eth3 have been configured in many ways, but to figure out which can be the problem I've connected them(one by one) to a network with DHCP, then call dhcpclient eth2 or eth3, and when ifconfig down the computer still hangs. So IMHO the configuration does not matter.

The modprobe.conf file looks as follows:

```
alias eth0 igb
alias eth1 igb
alias scsi_hostadapter ahci
install vtune_drv /opt/intel/vtune/mknod_vtune.sh
remove vtune_drv /opt/intel/vtune/rmnod_vtune.sh
alias char-major-10-111 mdm
```

igb and e1000e modules are loaded and I can see them with lsmod. 
`lsmod` --> http://pastebin.com/jJ7kk8mn

what `lspci` shows on ehternet is at follows (2 first eth are eth0 and eth1)

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

`lspci` --> http://pastebin.com/j94fWUPw
`lspci -v` --> http://pastebin.com/HRdMttzm

Just in case anyone cares the bios information from dmidecode is :

```
Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes.
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: R4222X52   
    Release Date: 09/23/2009
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 4096 kB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        ESCD support is available
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 KB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        LS-120 boot is supported
        ATAPI Zip drive boot is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
    BIOS Revision: 8.15
```

The boot.log does not show any interesting information from my POV but , also here it goes:

```
Aug  9 23:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 00:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 00:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 01:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 01:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 02:00:02 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 02:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 03:00:02 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 03:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 04:00:02 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 04:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 05:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 05:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 06:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 06:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 07:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 07:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 08:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 08:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 09:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 09:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 10:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 10:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 11:00:01 s_sys@myserver45 IOCMDSTAT: CHECK
Aug 10 11:00:03 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
Aug 10 11:08:37 s_sys@myserver45 NET[22300]: /sbin/dhclient-script : updated /etc/resolv.conf
Aug 10 11:15:29 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: BOOT nb_io_adapters=1|nb_local_disks=2
Aug 10 11:15:29 s_sys@myserver45 IOSIGNAL: STATUS OK <A HREF=/storage/iostatus.php?node=myserver45>(I/O status details)</A><BR>All I/O resources are OK
```

/var/log/messages --> http://pastebin.com/wBQL1ESE

/var/log/kernel/info --> http://pastebin.com/3KzF9Hhu

And I don't know what else can be useful, let me know.

Comment: What is "Red Hat Linux" in this case? RHEL 4? RHEL 5.x? RHEL 6? Have you installed all the updates?

Comment: I a rhel 5.3 . How can I know that new updates fix this? I've been looking for the list of changes on each update without success.

Comment: Unless there's a clear changelog / RH Bugzilla entry describing a problem similar to yours fixed, there's no way for you to know other than the good old "install the updates, see if it fixed something" method.

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile to boot the machines off a LiveCD of some newer release or a different distro to see if the problem is reproducable there.

Comment: What does `cat /proc/interrups` show? What other devices use the IRQ line of these network cards? You might try to download and compile the newest e1000e driver from Intel (they even provide a spec-file for building rpms). I had a case with SLES10SP4 where the e1000e kernel module was faulty...

Comment: You should add @Nils when answering my comment - else I do not get notified. Your pastebins are gone. Can`t you update your question with the results instead?

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a 2.6.18 Kernel?

Perhaps it is suffering the same [problems](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15817/eng/README.txt):

MSI-X Issues with Kernels between 2.6.19 - 2.6.21 (inclusive)

---

Kernel panics and instability may be observed on any MSI-X hardware if you 
  use irqbalance with kernels between 2.6.19 and 2.6.21. If such problems are 
  encountered, you may disable the irqbalance daemon or upgrade to a newer 
  kernel.

This is from the newest e1000e readme from Intel. So try disabling `irqbalance`.